# Facebook Pixel - saves jsmith@example.com as jsmith\u0040example.com

Tags: unicode-string, facebook-pixel

My Facebook Pixel Code:

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
        n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('set','agent','tmgoogletagmanager', 'XXXXXXXXX');
fbq('trackCustom', "UserLoggedIn", { em: 'jsmith@example.com' });
```

When I send a email variable with @ then Facebook Pixel replaces it with \u0040

jsmith@example.com -> jsmith\u0040example.com

Why?

// Encoding on my page is utf-8

Comment: That’s just the `@` converted to unicode character notation ... Why, is this causing any actual issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. The question I have, does Facebook still understand this? Or should Facebook be displaying email@email.com because email\u0040email.com might not be registered by Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will return you the email already in decode format. If still you are getting this issue then You can decode it again.

For better solution can you tell me where are you wants this email ?